# Access Crosstab Query: based on sales totals within TWO date ranges

Tags: sql, ms-access, crosstab

I'm looking for a way to create an Access crosstab query reporting sales totals by 'Brand', for two different date ranges.:

- For Distributor: "DistID" (column, not visible)
- Sales Totals: "Sales" (column)
- TWO different date ranges: "depDate" for Period 1 and Period 2 (column):

  - `Period1 = Between [forms]![frmRPT_YTDDepl_SF]![BDT1] And [forms]![frmRPT_YTDDepl_SF]![EDT1]`
  - `Period2 = Between [forms]![frmRPT_YTDDepl_SF]![BDT2] And [forms]![frmRPT_YTDDepl_SF]![EDT2]`
- Brands = "DprodBrand" (rows)

Currently, I have TWO separate crosstab queries for each period, working properly. -> CODE BELOW.

I am looking for a way to create ONE query displaying Brand's sales totals for each date range, in two separate columns or one crosstab query.

Period1:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(tblDepletions_DETAIL.detQuan) AS Sales
SELECT tblProducts_DEPL.DprodBrand
FROM tblDepletions INNER JOIN (tblProducts_DEPL INNER JOIN     tblDepletions_DETAIL ON tblProducts_DEPL.DprodZSKU = tblDepletions_DETAIL.detZSKU) ON tblDepletions.depID = tblDepletions_DETAIL.detDeplID
WHERE (((tblDepletions.depDate) Between [forms]![frmRPT_YTDDepl_SF]![BDT1]     And [forms]![frmRPT_YTDDepl_SF]![EDT1]) AND ((tblDepletions.depDistID)=132))
GROUP BY tblProducts_DEPL.DprodBrand
ORDER BY tblProducts_DEPL.DprodBrand
PIVOT Format([depDate],"yy")-(Format(Date(),"yy"))+2 In (1,2);
```

Period2:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(tblDepletions_DETAIL.detQuan) AS Sales
SELECT tblProducts_DEPL.DprodBrand
FROM tblDepletions INNER JOIN (tblProducts_DEPL INNER JOIN tblDepletions_DETAIL ON tblProducts_DEPL.DprodZSKU = tblDepletions_DETAIL.detZSKU) ON tblDepletions.depID = tblDepletions_DETAIL.detDeplID
WHERE (((tblDepletions.depDate) Between [forms]![frmRPT_YTDDepl_SF]![BDT2] And [forms]![frmRPT_YTDDepl_SF]![EDT2]) AND ((tblDepletions.depDistID)=132))
GROUP BY tblProducts_DEPL.DprodBrand
ORDER BY tblProducts_DEPL.DprodBrand
PIVOT Format([depDate],"yy")-(Format(Date(),"yy"))+2 In (1,2);
```

Many Thanks!!! ~~  Jacob

Comment: Thank You All for your ideas and collaboration!  I greatly appreciate your assistance and presence in this effort!
==============
**Accepted Solutionby:Dale Fye (Access MVP)2016-10-24**

I'm not sure you need a CrossTab for this.

`Select DProdBrand, 
SUM(IIF([DepDate] BETWEEN [Forms]![frmRpt_YTDDepl_SF]![BDT1] 
AND [[forms]![frmRPT_YTDDepl_SF]![EDT1], [Sales], 0) as Period1, 
SUM(IIF([DepDate] Between [forms]![frmRPT_YTDDepl_SF]![BDT2] 
AND [forms]![frmRPT_YTDDepl_SF]![EDT2], [Sales], 0) as Period2, 
SUM([Sales]) as [Sales Total]
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY DProdBrand`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By: Dale Fye (Access MVP):

I'm not sure you need a CrossTab for this.

```
Select DProdBrand, 
SUM(IIF([DepDate] BETWEEN [Forms]![frmRpt_YTDDepl_SF]![BDT1] 
AND [[forms]![frmRPT_YTDDepl_SF]![EDT1], [Sales], 0) as Period1, 
SUM(IIF([DepDate] Between [forms]![frmRPT_YTDDepl_SF]![BDT2] 
AND [forms]![frmRPT_YTDDepl_SF]![EDT2], [Sales], 0) as Period2, 
SUM([Sales]) as [Sales Total]
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY DProdBrand
```

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28978325/Access-Crosstab-Query-based-on-sales-totals-within-TWO-date-ranges.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider simply joining the two saved, crosstab queries like any other pair of queries or tables using the *DprodBrand* as join key:

```
SELECT CrosstabQ1.DprodBrand, 
       CrosstabQ1.[1] As Period1_Year1, CrosstabQ2.[1] As Period2_Year1,
       CrosstabQ1.[2] As Period1_Year2, CrosstabQ2.[2] As Period2_Year2
FROM CrosstabQ1
INNER JOIN CrosstabQ2 ON CrosstabQ1.DprodBrand = CrosstabQ2.DprodBrand
```

Now if you only want one query to do it all, consider the conditional aggregate pivot query since crosstabs cannot be used as subqueries. Here you migrate `WHERE` to `IIF()` conditions:

```
SELECT p.DprodBrand,
       SUM(IIF((d.depDate BETWEEN [Forms]![frmRPT_YTDDepl_SF]![BDT1] 
                              AND [Forms]![frmRPT_YTDDepl_SF]![EDT1])
               AND (Format(d.[depDate],"yy")-(Format(Date(),"yy"))+2 = 1), 
               dt.detQuan, NULL)) AS Period1_Year1,

       SUM(IIF((d.depDate BETWEEN [Forms]![frmRPT_YTDDepl_SF]![BDT2]     
                              AND [Forms]![frmRPT_YTDDepl_SF]![EDT2)
               AND (Format(d.[depDate],"yy")-(Format(Date(),"yy"))+2 = 1), 
               dt.detQuan, NULL)) AS Period2_Year1,

       SUM(IIF((d.depDate BETWEEN [Forms]![frmRPT_YTDDepl_SF]![BDT1] 
                              AND [Forms]![frmRPT_YTDDepl_SF]![EDT1])
               AND (Format(d.[depDate],"yy")-(Format(Date(),"yy"))+2 = 2), 
               dt.detQuan, NULL)) AS Period1_Year2,

       SUM(IIF((d.depDate BETWEEN [Forms]![frmRPT_YTDDepl_SF]![BDT2]     
                              AND [Forms]![frmRPT_YTDDepl_SF]![EDT2])
               AND (Format(d.[depDate],"yy")-(Format(Date(),"yy"))+2 = 2), 
               dt.detQuan, NULL)) AS Period2_Year2

FROM tblDepletions d
INNER JOIN (tblProducts_DEPL p
INNER JOIN tblDepletions_DETAIL dt
     ON p.DprodZSKU = dt.detZSKU) 
     ON d.depID = dt.detDeplID

WHERE ((d.depDistID)=132)
GROUP BY p.DprodBrand
ORDER BY p.DprodBrand
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is Access, it might be simpler to save the two queries leaving out the ORDER BY.

Then create a new query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Q1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM Q2
ORDER BY DprodBrand
```